# Preinstall video drivers for motherboard migration?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

I want to refresh a machine running Windows 7 Professional. I have a new motherboard and processor for it. I tried to swap-in the board but Windows failed to boot around the time that drivers like video are loaded. I was able to get to a recovery console, but I could not find logs of the failed boot and Windows could not fix [unknown] errors.

I have the Intel drivers from [Intel Graphics Driver for Windows](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/26682/Graphics-Intel-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-15-40-) for the 5500 chipset. I attempted to run the installer, but it exited with an error message similar to *"the system does not meet minimum requirements"*. I'm guessing that's because its the existing system with an add-on video card, and not the new board with the 5500 chipset.

I was able to pre-install the drivers for audio and network adapter, but I'm having trouble with the Intel video drivers.

Is it possible to pre-install the video drivers in preparation for the refresh? If so, then how do I do it?

Comment: Although not very helpful, I just want to add that I've had very little success in upgrading to a different motherboard with Windows 7. It is usually easier to just reinstall the OS from scratch. (Windows 8 and 10 is much better at handling new hardware, though). Also, if you have an OEM version of Windows, the license will probably not be valid anymore.

Comment: Thanks Magnus. I'm trying to avoid the reinstall. And yeah, I have plenty of retail copies of Windows 7 to avoid licensing problems. I often criticize Microsoft for some of their practices, but I won't violate licensing terms like that. I believe they should be compensated for their work, just like anyone else.

Comment: You can ring MS to get the license fixed, that's the easy bit. Personally I'd use Acronis to either clone to a new drive, or backup & restore to the same drive, using their Universal Restore module, which can handle hardware changes like this.

Comment: This may be part of the solution: [Extract drivers as sys/inf files from infinst_autol.exe executable?](https://communities.intel.com/thread/12591) I may not be able to preinstall them, but I may be able to unpack them and have them ready for safe mode.

Comment: Before changing motherboard, delete old graphics driver. Then, on reboot, they need to re-detect and install it.

Answer (score 1):

Extract the `win64_154034.4624.zip` with 7-zip and install the driver with [DriverStoreExplorer](https://github.com/lostindark/DriverStoreExplorer/releases/latest) by running the tool as admin, click on `Add package`

[image]

and select the `igdlh64.inf` file of the driver.

[image]